# How do I create hypermedia links in custom serializer with Spring Data Rest

Tags: serialization, abstract-class, spring-data-rest

I have a abstract class and two implementations:

```
public abstract class Attribute {
  // some properties
}

public class CustomAttribute extends Attribute{
  private String property1;
}

public class DefaultAttribute extends Attribute{
  private String property2;
}
```

There's another class, which includes these attributes:

```
public class Step{
  private List<Attribute> attributes;
}
```

Now when `Step` gets serialized, the self link is missing. I need the self reference, since I want to update the attributes. According to the documentation, jackson needs a little help deciding which class to use. But that does not help, because I need to use both classes. So I build a custom serializer (and registered with a module) for `Step` and now I wonder how I can construct the link myself. I couldn't find anything in the Spring Data Rest docs regarding this. Since Spring Data Rest adds these links automatically, I think there might be a way to have the protocol/hostname/port information available in the `JsonSerializer`. How do I get the information in my custom serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I use the `linkTo()` function to get the hostname and port and I manually set the rest of the resource URL in my custom serializer.

```
final Link attributeLink = linkTo(CustomAttributeRepository.class)
    .slash("/api")
    .slash("customAttributes")
    .slash(attribute.getIdentifier()).withSelfRel();
//@formatter:off
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("_links");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("self");
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                jsonGenerator.writeStringField("href", attributeLink.getHref());
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
//@formatter:on
```